# Sheets table from URL with pagination

Tags: google-sheets, csv, importdata

I have a question about importing .csv/.xml tables from url into Google spreadsheets. Maybe someone has any advice on how to import few csv tables from url that has pagination? I could do it manually but there is too many pages to add. I have started with something like this:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(importdata("https://example.com?page="&(1+...)))`

Though I'm not sure if my approach is right... Maybe someone has any advice?

Comment: What do you mean by "csv table from url that has pagination"?

Comment: I have website api URL that outputs .csv table format (I can also choose to use .xml .json) and there are a lot of pages of content that I need to transfer into Google sheets, there I'm able to edit it easily the way I want...

Comment: So basically you have a lot of URLs that have same pattern, changing only the last characters. What about the formula you started with? Does it work?

Comment: Yep, you understood right. It doesn't really work, I'm not sure how to change number (add 1) every iteration and I'd like to be able to choose how many times to repeat (number of pages). I have surfed arround the web for the answer quite a lot, but couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your formula is on row 1, you could use ROW() for page 1

```
importdata("https://example.com?page="&ROW())
```

For page 2, use the same formula on row 2, and so on.

AFAIK import functions doesn't work with ARRAYFORMULA

Comment: Thank you a lot. I will try it out tomorrow, it's quite late here... :)